# configure nginx in passenger 3.0.2 stand alone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

In older passengers (3.0.0) it was possible to configure the standalone nginx passenger (`passenger start`). In the `.passenger`-Dir there was a complete nginx installation (`3.0.0-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-macosx-10.6/nginx`).

In 3.0.2 there only is a sbin-dir. the config directory is missing. Where can I find the config files?

Comment: I want to configure additional mime types besides the default mime types for a small app of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phusion-passenger/CsMDrj8SAzY/jR_7BzNgFD4J):

> We do not plan on supporting this. Phusion Passenger Standalone is
>   meant to be its own web server, designed to handle the most basic use
>   cases very very well at the expense of customizability. That it
>   happens to be using Nginx under the hood today is an implementation
>   detail that the user should not bother with; it may very well happen
>   that we one day swap Nginx with something else. If you want any kind
>   of complex customization you should use Phusion Passenger for Nginx
>   instead.

Comment: The messenger of bad news! :(

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger :)